# Swift: Setting a new UIImage in CellForRowAtIndexPath does not show up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

this is my issue: I am working on an iOS App in Swift. I have a table view which represents meetings. I have created a custom cell. This cell contains an image. A default one is set in the storyboard.

Now depending on the current row data, I want to visualize, if the meeting is expired or new.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("meetingListCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MeetingListCell
     let meeting = meetingList![indexPath.row]

     cell.meeting.text = meeting.text

     if(meeting.isExpired()) {
         cell.meetingIconImageView.image = UIImage(named: "meeting-expired")
     } else {
         cell.meetingIconImageView.image = UIImage(named: "meeting-new")
     }
     cell.setNeedsLayout()
     cell.setNeedsDisplay()
     return cell
 }
```

But it just does not change the image. Maybe this is a silly one but actually it drives me nuts ;-)

Many thanks in advance
Cheers
John

Comment: 1. Is `isExpired()` returning the expected result for the meeting/cell?  2. Do you have images named "meeting-expired" and "meeting-new" in your project's asset catalog?

Comment: Does it work with some other image? Is there actually an image with the name you specified?

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in that method and determine if `cell.meetingIconImageView.image` is actually being set?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing specific wrong with your code as far as I can see but here are some things to try

Set a breakpoint and make sure that UIImage constructor returns an image and not just nil.

if it's nil:

- Check that the images are added to the project properly and that it's named as you expect.
- Check that the image has a target set to the **projects target**. Sometimes the images gets added incorrectly and is not really part of what gets built when you actually run the app. Adding them to `Images.xcassets` instead of just loosely in the project might fix this in an easy way.

if it's not nil:

- Check that your imageView has a proper frame set. You can view it in the `Debug View Hierarchy` function as your app is running. Trying to set the constraints to a fixed size as a test might help you find any issues related to this.

On another note you really shouldn't need to do

```
cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Comment: Hi Moriya, thanks for your thoughts and your feedback, that in general code did sould work. After a night, I double checked everything and then deleted out the image from the media.xcassets and re-uploaded it which finally (whyever) solved the issue. Really no clue why, but both your and @ArturOlszak reply helped a lot. And thanks for the confirmation, that `cell.setNeedsLayout()` and `cell.setNeedsDisplay()` are not needed what I was not sure about.

Answer (score 1):

I would debug it with those steps:

1. Check are your images not null when you assign them meetingIconImageView.
2. Check are images visible in built in UIImageView in UITableViewCell (cell.imageView.image = UIImage...).
3. Check is meetingIconImageView actually visible in view - set red background. Maybe constrains are messed up.
4. Check are you doing something wrong in your custom cell - maybe outlet is wrongly connected or you're doing something crazy in init method.

If still wrong then take a beer and check it tomorrow morning ;-)

Comment: Hi ArturOlszak, thanks for the thoughts. Especially the last one worked (the beer and the morning thing ;-) I double checked everything this morning and at the end, I deleted out the icon from media.xcassets and re-loaded it in and it worked. No clue why not before but this solved the issue.